# Proper way to work with stored procedures in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I need to work with stored procedures, with the help of Entity Framework Core. This is my function:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckIfUserRegistered(string phoneNumber, DateTime dateOfBirth)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phoneNumber))
        {
            return false;
        }
        using (var cmd = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.CheckIfUserRegistered";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@phoneNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = phoneNumber });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dateOfBirth", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = dateOfBirth });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@registered", SqlDbType.Bit) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });

            if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
            }

            await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

            return (bool)cmd.Parameters["@registered"].Value;
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure, with the correctness of this function, is this the right way to work with stored procedures in EF Core? Don't I have problems with forgotten connections, memory leakings, etc?

Comment: Minor detail, but I would rename the method to `CheckIfUserRegisteredAsync`, since appending `Async` to the end of an asynchronous method is a popular practice. You will see this pattern used a lot in the .NET Framework for example e.g. `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`.

Comment: @JasonEvans I've thinking about it, and decided not to do this, because absolutely all my methods are async.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest thing I would change is to return the connection to the state you found it.

```
bool isOpen = cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open;
if (!isOpen)
{
    cmd.Connection.Open();
}

await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

if (!isOpen)
{
    cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

Then, from there, I would create a helper method to build the `SqlParameter` objets for you:

```
private SqlParameter BuildParamter(string name, SqlDbType type, object value, ParameterDirection? direction)
{
    var parameter = new SqlParameter(name, type);

    if (value != null)
    {
        parameter.Value = value;
    }

    if (direction.HasValue)
    {
        parameter.Direction = direction.Value;
    }

    return parameter;
}
```

Then your parameters go from:

> ```
> cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@phoneNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = phoneNumber });
> cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dateOfBirth", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = dateOfBirth });
>
> cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@registered", SqlDbType.Bit) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });
> ```

To:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(BuildParameter("@phoneNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, phoneNumber));
cmd.Parameters.Add(BuildParameter("@dateOfBirth", SqlDbType.Date, dateOfBirth));

cmd.Parameters.Add(BuildParameter("@registered", SqlDbType.Bit, null, ParameterDirection.Output));
```

It's less verbose, but if you build a lot of `SqlParameter` objects it might be handy to have one method you can use for all of them. (You can optionally add a `int? size` parameter to the method as well.)

Then, extract a `SetStoredProcedure` method which would take the input `SqlCommand` and `string`, set the type and command text to `"dbo." + name`, then you add the parameters, then `ExecuteStoredProcedure` would do the connection checking and then you can return your `cmd.Parameters["@registered"].Value` as you are. In the end something like:

```
SetStoredProcedure("CheckIfUserRegistered", cmd):

cmd.Parameters.Add(BuildParameter("@phoneNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, phoneNumber));
cmd.Parameters.Add(BuildParameter("@dateOfBirth", SqlDbType.Date, dateOfBirth));

cmd.Parameters.Add(BuildParameter("@registered", SqlDbType.Bit, null, ParameterDirection.Output));

ExecuteStoredProcedure(cmd);

return (bool)cmd.Parameters["@registered"].Value;
```

Optionally with your `async`/`await` pattern.

This way, if you create more stored procedures it's less work to make them operate.

Answer (score -4):

That's way too heavy to call a stored procedure. Here is my case.
I have a SP called "DeleteBusiness" which takes 1 parameter.
Entity Framework 6 will generate a method in `DataModel.context.cs` as follows,

```
public virtual int DeleteBusiness(Nullable<int> p_COMPID)
{
    var p_COMPIDParameter = p_COMPID.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("p_COMPID", p_COMPID) :
        new ObjectParameter("p_COMPID", typeof(int));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("DeleteBusiness", p_COMPIDParameter);
}
```

Then in my code I just call the method in DbContext like this,

```
DbContext.DeleteBusiness(compId);
```

Comment: I'm not sure, do we have such method in EF Core?

Comment: The method you are proposing will only return the number of rows affected. According to the [docs on ObjectParameter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2) it can also not deal with out parameters (aka. return values) of Stored Procedures. As such the code proposed can not be used to replace the code from the question.

Comment: @YuriyN. The freamwork will generate the method.

Comment: @Vogel612 It's also possible to return a value like this, var pResult = new ObjectParameter("pResult", typeof(int));
                         dbContext.uspSubmitSale(data.Id, pResult);